# How to write a key pair generic "type" typescirpt

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm waiting to write a key value pair type for flat objects.
But when I user this type in a global s type file I get this error.

```
// 1. this is what I'm currently using. 
type KEY_VALUES = { [k: string | number]: any; };

// 2. I thought it should be something like this.
type KEY_VALUES = { [k: string | number]: [value: any]; };

1. Error: An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

2. Error: An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Consider using a mapped object type instead.

Have you tried that?

```
type KEY_VALUES = {
    [k in string | number]: any;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @SeanAH solution, you can use [string pattern index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures):

```js
type KEY_VALUES = { [k: string | `${number}`]: [value: any]; };
```